# The element 'content' already has a child with alias 'product_list'

Tags: magento-2.1

In every page load, I am getting the following error in **exception.log** of my Magento 2 website.

> main.CRITICAL: The element 'content' already has a child with alias
> 'product_list' {"exception":"[object]
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): The
> element 'content' already has a child with alias 'product_list' at
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:611)"} []

Please help to solve this error. I don't know which extension is causing this error.

I have installed [Darsh_Callforprice](https://github.com/Darshanmodi1427/Darsh_Callforprice) extension to add an option to make the call for price in some products.

If you have faced this kind of error previously then, please let me know how you solve this.

> UPDATE

When I search `"product_list"` in all the `xml` inside my `app/code` folder I am getting the following result.

**code\Darsh\Callforprice\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml (1 hit)**
**..Please see the code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z0hV5f9L_ae4ENJV4KXl-wSWwmznir9G/view?usp=sharing)**

```
 Line 6: <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.customlist" as="product_list" template="Darsh_Callforprice::list.phtml">
```

**code\Mageplaza\Shopbybrand\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml (1 hit)**

**Please see the code [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1X4CBbphqn6RYwrTRrRFABle5-0kglMoX?usp=sharing)**

```
Line 7: <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" >
```

**code\Mageplaza\Shopbybrand\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml-orginal (1 hit)**

```
Line 7: <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_catalog::product/list.phtml" >
```

**code\Magiccart\Magicproduct\view\frontend\layout\magicproduct_bestseller_index.xml (1 hit)**

```
Line 30: <block class="Magiccart\Magicproduct\Block\Product\ProductList" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

**code\Magiccart\Magicproduct\view\frontend\layout\magicproduct_featured_index.xml (1 hit)**

```
Line 30: <block class="Magiccart\Magicproduct\Block\Product\ProductList" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

**code\Magiccart\Magicproduct\view\frontend\layout\magicproduct_latest_index.xml (1 hit)**

```
Line 30: <block class="Magiccart\Magicproduct\Block\Product\ProductList" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

**code\Magiccart\Magicproduct\view\frontend\layout\magicproduct_newproduct_index.xml (1 hit)**

```
Line 30: <block class="Magiccart\Magicproduct\Block\Product\ProductList" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you have two `catalog_category_view.xml` and both are trying to alias `product_list` in their XML. It would be easier to answer if I could see the whole content of those two files.

But changing one `product_list` to something else (`another_product_list`) would fix the exception. However, you will need to add `another_product_list` in the `phtml` file too.

**Bit of context:**

When Magento is calling `getChildHtml('produt_list')` it is struggling to determine which one to call, since both of them are aliased the same name. So the rule of thumb, in the same parent node (throughout the layout), you shouldn't include same alias.

Comment: This is super helpful. Could you please check the question again . I have uploaded the path for codes and you can see the code in gitlab and google drive. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Looking at your provided link: https://github.com/Darshanmodi1427/Darsh_Callforprice/blob/master/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml I don't see the same content in line 6. Looks like you may have made some changes.

Comment: Sorry . New Link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z0hV5f9L_ae4ENJV4KXl-wSWwmznir9G/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Full-extension link:  https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qdP-7eLUkazeib8mEh2O9nb14vgFY-GU?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah, you should just change one of the `product_list` to `another_product_list`.

Comment: Great. This is working. I changed product_list  to product_customlist and now that error is solved. However i am getting [2022-07-11 04:38:11] main.INFO: 1 [] [], [2022-07-11 04:38:11] main.INFO: 5 [] [] this entry repeatedly in system.log now and it is added multiple times when a website visit. Also getting [2022-07-11 04:42:14] main.CRITICAL: Bucket does not exist [] []

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14-_3ai4RG9QrXq4pllEvpsnm2XolDBRI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you please assist me in resolving that issue as well, or do I need to post a new question.?

Comment: Yeah, you should ask new qst but that may be hard to resolve. It could be a default (no-harm) msg. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. May God bless you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137686/discussion-between-abilash-erikson-and-adarsh-khatri).

Answer (score 2):

If I am interpreting the error correctly there is a module or theme file that tries to add a block or container with the name or alias "product_list" to the "content" container.

Do a search in your codebase filtered by .xml files only and add "product_list" (include the quotation marks) as the search term. In a clean magento installation it should only show 1 file in the magento catalog module. The file that breaks your magento should be among the other search results you are getting.

Comment: Thank you. This is super helpful. Could you please check my question once again, I updated the question with the search result.

Answer (score 0):

In 'theme OR module' layout file 'content' are use multiple times like as="content" that.so remove it and check.